# Creating Simple Grid Layout in React Native

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I'm trying to create the following layout in my React Native app but haven't been able to get it right. The phone number, address and schedules are currently sitting in the middle of the screen and the "Interactive section" is at the bottom of the screen.

What am I doing wrong here? I'd appreciate some help with this layout. Thank you!

BTW, in the following image, I put the borders to show you what I want to achieve. I actually don't want to see any borders around contact info, schedule or interactive sections. The whole thing should just float on white background.

[image]

Here's the code in my component:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
   <View style={styles.title}>
      <Text style={styles.titleText}>Global Enterprises</Text>
   </View>
   <View style={styles.contactInfoSection}>
      <View style={styles.phoneNumberSection}>
         <View>
            <Text>212.555.1234</Text>
         </View>
         <View>
            <Text>1 Global Way</Text>
            <Text>New York, NY 12345</Text>
         </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.scheduleSection}>
         <Text>Mon - Fri 8:30 - 5:30</Text>
         <Text>Sat - Sun Closed</Text>
      </View>
   </View>
   <View>
       <Text style={styles.interactSection}>Other stuff</Text>
   </View>
</View>
```

Here's my stylesheet for this particular screen:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create(
   {
      contactInfoSection: {
         alignContent: 'flex-start',
         alignItems: 'flex-start',
         alignSelf: 'flex-start',
         flex: 2,
         flexDirection: 'row',
         marginTop: 20
      },
      container: {
         alignContent: 'flex-start',
         flex: 1,
         flexGrow: 1,
         padding: 20
      },
      interactSection: {
         flex: 3
      },
      locationSection: {
         alignItems: 'center',
         flex: 1
      },
      phoneNumberSection: {
         alignContent: 'center',
         alignItems: 'center',
         alignSelf: 'center',
         flex: 1
      },
      scheduleSection: {
         alignContent: 'center',
         alignItems: 'center',
         alignSelf: 'center',
         flex: 1
      },
      title: {
         alignItems: 'center',
         flex: 1,
         marginTop: 5
      },
      titleText: {
         fontSize: 17,
         fontWeight: 'bold'
      }
   }
);

export { styles };
```

Comment: Your question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update `contactInfoSection` and `title` style. Please amend

This

```
  contactInfoSection: {
    alignContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    flex: 2,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  title: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 5,
  },
```

to this

```
contactInfoSection: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  title: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 5,
  },
```

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you. I definitely works. I just need to understand why it does. I thought I was allocating how much space title and contact info sections were going to take on the screen by adding the `flex` attributes.

Comment: When we don’t set flex then the element will try to take space required by their child elements. So in your case we removed flex from contactinfo and title section which makes contactinfo to fit into space needed by their children. If you want to give them some extra space then padding or margin are more appropriate then flex.

Comment: Thanks again for the explanation. I really appreciate it.